# Blank page gets downloaded (toDataURL())

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
assets.forEach(function(v) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id     = "canvas" + v.name;
    canvas.width  = 200;
    canvas.height = 150;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'file:///path/to/file/' + v.name;
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height-256, 0, 0, 200, 150);
    };

    // This is working. Renders correctly and visible.
    $('#test2').append(canvas);

    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: canvas.toDataURL(),
        filename: 'file:///path/to/file/test-' + canvas.id + '.png'
    });
});
```

Hi All, this is my code above. What I am trying is to download an image which is a smaller version of `img`. It all works fine, the canvas is created, I can see it when appended to an element `$('#test2').append(canvas);`. But when I want to download it, it downloads blank one.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is valid image drawn when canvas is appended ?

Comment: Yes, it is visible when appended! @Rayon

Comment: Is the blank image of the same dimensions as the valid image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke `download` method in `Image.onload` handler as by the time `download` method is invoked, `Image` is not yet *drawn*

```js
assets.forEach(function(v) {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.id = "canvas" + v.name;
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 150;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'file:///path/to/file/' + v.name;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height - 256, 0, 0, 200, 150);
    $('#test2').append(canvas);

    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: canvas.toDataURL(),
      filename: 'file:///path/to/file/test-' + canvas.id + '.png'
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_